# Angularjs Upload, php $_REQUEST empty array on some files

Tags: php, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
 Upload.upload({
            url: "/ajaxHandler_importBaProds.php",
            data: {
                file: $scope.file,
                catId: $scope.catId,
                submit: 'upload',
            }
        }).then(function(res) {
           console.log(res);
        })
```

and the following php file:

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);die;
```

Which return

```
array (size=0)
```

on some files.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

in php ini,

set `upload_max_filesize` and `upload_max_filesize` as big as the your biggest file